# What is Alina's book at the end of The Equalizer?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-equalizer

At the end of The Equalizer Alina shows McCall a book and the following is said:

> Um. I'm reading now.
> Oh, no
> Yeah!
> Very good.
> I know. I got it from a used book store. The guy there recommended it to me. It's good.

There are a few shots of [the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkH1J.png) but from awkward angles. The film gives the book little weight, unlike [other books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F70Bc.jpg) in the film.

**What is the book, and does it have any special significance in relation to characters or plot?**

Answer (score 3):

The book in question is "The Razor's Edge" by W. Somerset Maugham.

[image]

Comment: I fixed your image for you, and comparing it with the screenshot linked to in the question, this certainly does look like the correct book.

Comment: @F1Krazy: it certainly does, I agree, was uploading the same image :)

Comment: @F1Krazy: thanks for help! I was definitely doing smth wrong when I tried to post this image for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

### We don't know

However, what the book is *is not important*.

What the dialogue is intending to show is that Alina/Teri has completely turned her life around...the quote you gave is merely part of a longer piece which shows the context. Some additional extracts...

> I know. I got it from a used book store. The guy there recommended it to me. It’s good. **I got a job too. Like a real job with real hours and stuff.**

> When they gave me my stuff back at the hospital, there was this envelope with my name on it. Almost ten thousand dollars inside and a ticket out of town. I don’t know, probably hush money, right?

> Who cares? A new start.

> Well someone once told me I could be whoever I wanted to be.

Basically, before, Alina was merely an uneducated prostitute with minor aspirations to a singing career. Now she has a job, is improving herself by reading and has a positive outlook.

The point of the scene is to show how effective Robert's actions have been.

Comment: Because of the recent mardown overhaul I have to ask, but I suppose the quotes being all separate blocks is intentional since they're from different parts of the scene?

Comment: Yes, they are just Alina's words, I took our the rest of the conversation with Robert which didn't add any additional information. Thanks for checking!